# Some advice in optimizing an axis-aligned shape-only tetromino input and rectangular output jigsaw solving algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to make a solver for the "[Sigil Puzzle](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=354590899)" (Which basically a jigsaw where only the shape matters, the shape only can be that of an axis aligned tetromino and a board size) of the [Talos Principle](https://store.steampowered.com/app/257510/). And I have already a working back tracer that solves this kind of Jigsaw.

The problem is that my algorithm struggles with some jigsaws that are present in the game (presumably human solvable, even not human should be given the torture of try to solve any of those, including those that are somehow more solvable but still big like [gray](https://guides.gamepressure.com/talosprinciple/guide.asp?ID=29129)).

My code of the backtrack part is the following

```rust
pub fn backtrace(
    step_pool: &mut Vec<SolveStep>,
    table: &Table,
    tetronimos: &[Tetronimo],
    tetronimo_index: usize,
) -> Such {
    if tetronimos.is_empty() || tetronimo_index >= tetronimos.len() {
        return SolveState::Success;
    }

    let current_tetronimo = &tetronimos[tetronimos];

    for y in 0..table.height {
        for x in 0..(table.matrix.len() / table.height) {
            for rotation in [Rotation::Null, Rotation::R90, Rotation::R180, Rotation::R270] {
                if !can_tetronimo_be_added_to_table_without_overlay(table, current_tetronimo, x, y, rotation) {
                    continue;
                }

                let table = add_tetronimo_to_table(&table, current_tetronimo, x, y, rotation).unwrap();

                let search_status = backtrace(step_pool, &table, &tetronimos, tetronimo_index + 1);

                match search_status {
                    SearchStatus::FoundNothing => {
                        continue;
                    }
                    SearchStatus::Success => {
                        step_pool.push(SolveStep {
                            x,
                            y,
                            rotation,
                            tetronimo_index,
                        });
                        return SearchStatus::Success;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    SolveState::NothingFound
}
```

I identify that my algorithm is O(M^N) where M is the number of tiles in the table, and N is the number of pieces, with is polynomial with respect of table size and polynomial to respect to number of pieces, which means that an theoretically human solvable 6x6 table and 9 tetrominos becomes 101 559 956 669 seconds of time to solve at least. Which is way too big to be acceptable.

My research found complicated algorithms with concepts that (1) are beyond my understanding and (2) are overkill for an only axis aligned tetromino shapes jigsaw with rectangular outputs. (This may be because I am bad at research)

These are some

1. http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/R.Yu/jigsaw/Jigsaw_final_compressed.pdf
   Really overkill and complicated
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S131915781830394X
   The same
3. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_and_bound
   What is this?
4. https://github.com/byWulf/jigsawlutioner
   "Simpler" but does not work in most tetrominos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You desperately need to reduce the number of elements that you try at every iteration:

Do not iterate over the whole table (WxH) trying to add another piece - it's WxH times more efficient to try to place all the pieces to the first unoccupied element -- because that's where it has the fit, leaving no gaps.

Do precompute the rotations of the available pieces. Compute only the necessary rotations. (A square has no rotations).

Insert a similar piece just once (when having a dictionary of e.g. 'L,L,I,I,Q,Q', there are just 7 variations to be tried. 4 rotational variants for the L, 2 rotational variants for I and one for Q.

An implementation strategy: create a bit map for all the rotations and the board. The bitmap for the board should occupy at least 4 last rows (or what ever is the height of the tallest tetramino.

```
Initial board for 4x6: 
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1
   1 1 1 1 1 1 1  == 0b00000010000001000000100000011111111;
```

All the pieces must be converted to bit maps of the same width:

```
   1 1 0 0 0 0 0
   0 1 1 0 0 0 0 == 'A0' = 0b11000000110000;

   1 0 0 0 0 0 0 -- the rotation wraps to other side
   1 0 0 0 0 0 1
   0 0 0 0 0 0 1 == 'A1' = 0b1000001000010000001;
```

The rotated variation given above can not be inserted to an empty board, because `last_4_rows_of_board & A1 != 0`.

With this kind of technique I had a 100MHz 80486 to find all the 1200+ solutions of pentaminos in 5x12 grid under a second. With modern 64-bit machines, that might fit most of the tables in a single register, I would expect the solutions for all the small puzzles to be found in milliseconds.

Comment: How can Implement the ''Do not iterate over the whole table (WxH) trying to add another piece - it's WxH times more efficient to try to place all the pieces to the first unoccupied element -- because that's where it has the fit, leaving no gaps.'" Tip?

Comment: You start obviously from the first element `i=0`, corresponding to `y = 0, x = 0`, placing one unique element from the list of unused blocks. Then you need to scan forward to find the first unused slot, which might correspond to `i=2, or `y=0,x=2`.

Comment: You mean?
`
    for i in 0..table.matrix.len() {
        let width = table.matrix.len() / table.height;
        let x = i % width;
        let y = (i - x) / width;

        if table.matrix[i] {
            continue;
        }
`
instead of
`for y in 0..table.height {
        for x in 0..(table.matrix.len() / table.height) {

Comment: Then I am complete lost in how to implement it.

Comment: Well, actually yes. What your approach does, is to scan the first free slot and that's enough. One can make it a bit/much more efficient by remembering the position where one was starting at the beginning of each call the the backtracking, and continue from that position+1. But even without that the approach should give a decent speed up.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how to get an capture of the screen in Linux with Wayland?